# Alternative to applying slicing of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am trying to rank authors using an intersection of two metrics (where averaging wouldn't make sense) for each observation.

So far the only way I have done it was to apply a slice of the dataframe and take the unique number of authors but it's really slow.

I was wondering if there was a faster solution to this problem of ranking with multiple criteria.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", 2, 0], ["b", 3, 0.15], ["b", 3, 0.4], ["c", 7, 0.49], ["d", 3, 0.17]], columns=['author', 'metric1', 'metric2'])

df['score'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(df[(df['metric2']>= x['metric2']) & (df['metric1']>= x['metric1'])]['author'].unique()), axis=1)
```

Comment: I think I would be tempted to sort the data then iterate.

Comment: The issue is that sorting implies to have some sort of idea about which metric is more important and I want to be agnostic about that.

Answer (score 0):

With your current solution you're filtering the dataframe each time to count the number of authors that are greater or equal in both metrics, which is indeed slow because you're filtering the whole dataframe for each row. There are a couple ways we can rank according to multiple columns in a way that treats them as having equal importance, which don't give the exact same results as your example but may be what you're looking for. These are both ways to make adding or averaging the metrics make sense.

**Adding Together Ranks**

One approach is to use `.rank()` to get rankings of the columns individually, then add them together.

```
 df['score'] = df['metric1'].rank(ascending = False) + df['metric2'].rank(ascending = False)
```

then we get

```
print(df)
  author  metric1  metric2  score
0      a        2     0.00   10.0
1      b        3     0.15    7.0
2      b        3     0.40    5.0
3      c        7     0.49    2.0
4      d        3     0.17    6.0
```

**Z-Scores**

A useful tool for comparing and combining metrics that are on different scales is to convert them to [z-scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score). This turns the raw metric values into the number of standard deviations below or above the mean they represent, giving us the ability to treat the different metrics as though they had the same mean and standard deviation.

```
import numpy as np

df['z1'] = (df['metric1'] - df['metric1'].mean())/df['metric1'].std()
df['z2'] = (df['metric2'] - df['metric2'].mean())/df['metric2'].std()
df['score'] = df['z1'] + df['z2']
```

And that results in

```
print(df)
  author  metric1  metric2        z1        z2     score
0      a        2     0.00 -0.820783 -1.215022 -2.035805
1      b        3     0.15 -0.307794 -0.461909 -0.769703
2      b        3     0.40 -0.307794  0.793279  0.485486
3      c        7     0.49  1.744163  1.245147  2.989310
4      d        3     0.17 -0.307794 -0.361494 -0.669288
```

A nice thing about z-scores is it preserves the importance of differences. In this example you can see that in rows 1 and 4 we get very similar scores because z-scores respect the fact that .15 and .17 in metric 2 are very close. Whereas the rank method treats that difference as being the same size - 1 rank - as the difference between .17 and .40.

We can write this in a more compact way by using the `zscore` function from scipy.

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
df['score'] = np.sum(df[['metric1', 'metric2']].apply(zscore), axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I don't want to be in the position where (x,y) and (z,t) have the same final score if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Create temporary `key` column to assign unique id to each row

```
df['key'] = range(len(df))
```

Cross merge the dataframe

```
df1 = df.merge(df, how='cross', suffixes=['', '_r'])

#    author  metric1  metric2  key author_r  metric1_r  metric2_r  key_r
# 0       a        2     0.00    0        a          2       0.00      0
# 1       a        2     0.00    0        b          3       0.15      1
# 2       a        2     0.00    0        b          3       0.40      2
# 3       a        2     0.00    0        c          7       0.49      3
# 4       a        2     0.00    0        d          3       0.17      4
# 5       b        3     0.15    1        a          2       0.00      0
# 6       b        3     0.15    1        b          3       0.15      1
# 7       b        3     0.15    1        b          3       0.40      2
...
# 21      d        3     0.17    4        b          3       0.15      1
# 22      d        3     0.17    4        b          3       0.40      2
# 23      d        3     0.17    4        c          7       0.49      3
# 24      d        3     0.17    4        d          3       0.17      4
```

Evaluate the required condition for the metric

```
mask = df1.eval("`metric1` <= `metric1_r` and `metric2` <= `metric2_r`")

# 0      True
# 1      True
# 2      True
# 3      True
# 4      True
# 5     False
# 6      True
# 7      True
...
# 21    False
# 22     True
# 23     True
# 24     True
# dtype: bool
```

Groupby `key` and count the unique authors

```
count = df1['author_r'].where(mask).groupby(df1['key']).nunique()

# key
# 0    4
# 1    3
# 2    2
# 3    1
# 4    3
# Name: author_r, dtype: int64
```

Map the unique counts back to original dataframe

```
df['score'] = df.pop('key').map(count)

#   author  metric1  metric2  score
# 0      a        2     0.00      4
# 1      b        3     0.15      3
# 2      b        3     0.40      2
# 3      c        7     0.49      1
# 4      d        3     0.17      3
```

Comment: For some reason this appeared to be quite resource intensive.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) :

```
aut, mr1, mr2 = df.to_numpy().T

mask = (mr1 >= mr1[:, None]) & (mr2 >= mr2[:, None])

df["score"] = [len(np.unique(aut[m])) for m in mask]

# slower variant, `[df["author"].loc[m].nunique() for m in mask]`
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  author  metric1  metric2  score
0      a        2     0.00      4
1      b        3     0.15      3
2      b        3     0.40      2
3      c        7     0.49      1
4      d        3     0.17      3
```